# Hosting IdentityServer 4 on Linux

Tags: identityserver4

I'm a software architect and internally I'm using Identity Server on several projects starting from version 3. Usually I'm publish it on Windows Environment (so Windows Server + IIS + etc...).

Now, a new customer ask me if it's possible to publish IS on Linux machine (probably with RedHat as OS). Is it possible to host IS on linux machine?

Reading the IS's documentation, I found that a way may be hosting IS into Docker container. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

- You should create an Docker Linux-based Image which is able to host on windows and Linux.
- Also, you can create a Linux-based publish using dotnet core.